# where statement to filter specific datetime format sql bigquery

Tags: sql, datetime, parsing, filter, google-bigquery

I have a query that outputs data - row by row - and for each record I grab a value from `last_modified_date` column that is the latest date in that column BUT is not later than the `date` column's value. I save the new value in column `custom_last_modified_date`.
My data looks like this:

```
id           date           last_modified_date
A           03/01/22          2022-03-02 22:44
A           03/01/22          2022-02-01 05:14
A           03/01/01          2022-02-28 07:49
B           03/02/22          2022-03-20 07:49
B           03/02/22          2022-03-01 04:46
B           03/02/01          2022-02-28 09:24
```

The output is:

```
id           date        custom_last_modified_date
A           03/01/22          02/28/22
A           03/01/22          02/28/22
A           03/01/01          02/28/22
B           03/02/22          03/01/22
B           03/02/22          03/01/22
B           03/02/01          03/01/22
```

Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
id, 
date,
MAX(
        IF(
            date(
                string(
                    TIMESTAMP(
                        DATETIME(
                            parse_datetime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', last_modified_date)
                        ),
                        'America/New_York'
                    )
                )
            ) <= date,
            date(
                string(
                    TIMESTAMP(
                        DATETIME(
                            parse_datetime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', last_modified_date)
                        ),
                        'America/New_York'
                    )
                )
            ),
            null
        )
    ) OVER (PARTITION BY date, id) as custom_last_modified_date
FROM `my_table`
```

All works fine on sample, but because data is not very clean sometimes values in `last_modified_date` look like this: `"2021-0-3 05:50"` and then error message is: `Failed to parse`
Is there a way to JUST filter out the right format of the date in where clause or otherwise exclude bad values within the same query?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SAFE` prefix to ignore the parser errors, then you can filter the `null` rows:

```sql
-- Returns null if last_modified_date not match the expected pattern
SAFE.parse_datetime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', last_modified_date)
```

From the docs:

> If you begin a function with the SAFE. prefix, it will return NULL instead of an error.
>
> [...]
>
> BigQuery supports the use of the SAFE. prefix with most scalar functions that can raise errors, including STRING functions, math functions, DATE functions, DATETIME functions, TIMESTAMP functions, and JSON functions.

More info: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-reference#safe_prefix